# Living in RV (Recreational vehicle)

Tags: canada

Can I live in an Recreational vehicle or mobile home in Canada on a full-time basis while I am on Student Visa?

Comment: One issue is that you need a permanent address to get a driver's license, register an RV, and possibly the school will want one, and not just a post office box. Will you have another car to use besides the RV or mobile home?

Comment: @mkennedy, nope. only RV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.  I lived on a boat.  Note that you'll need a *residential* mailing address to avoid all sorts of complications.  There are databases of addresses that indicate weather or not an address is residential and some services like credit cards that will insist on a residential address for a personal credit card.